# Finding the 'cube roots' of a permutation

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

How do I find three elements $\sigma \in S_9$ such that $\sigma^3=(157)(283)(469)$?  Since the three $3$-cycles in $\sigma^3$ are disjoint, $|\sigma^3|=\operatorname{lcm}(3,3,3)=3$.  Then since $(\sigma^3)^3=\sigma^9=e$ we have that $|\sigma|=9$, so $\sigma$ is a $9$-cycle.  That is all I'm really able to say.

How do we intelligently/methodically find the desired elements?  A generalized approach is welcome as well.

Thanks.

Comment: What "three elements"?

Answer (score 3):

We may assume $\sigma=(1ab5cd7ef)$. Now $2$ can be any of $a,b,c,d,e,f$. Let's say $a=2$. Then we have $\sigma=(12b58d73f)$. Now $4$ can be any of $b,d,f$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** One is $\sigma=(124\,586\,739)$.

Comment: And so the other two are $(245867391)$ and $(458673912)$?  I see it now.

Comment: Well, these are all the same 9-cycle. Write $(571)$ instead of $(157)$...

Comment: Oh, duh.  Since we're cubing $\sigma$, we need the consecutive elements in each disjoint cycle to be $3$ apart.  This then holds true if we permute each of the first, middle, and last three entries of $\sigma$ in the same way.  Am I correct in thinking that this implies there are actually 6 such elements?

Comment: Well, according to Gerry's answer, it seems that rather $6\cdot 3$ such permutations exist.

Answer (score 0):

Now you have $|\sigma|=9$, you can express $\sigma$ as $$\sigma = (a_1a_2...a_9)$$
Subsequently, through some manual calculation, you can obtain $$\sigma ^ 3 = (a_1a_4a_7)(a_2a_5a_8)(a_3a_6a_9)$$
By comparing this result to $3!$ permutation of $(157)(283)(469)$, you can assign each $a_i$ to the corresponding position in the permutation.