# Find $\sigma$, when $\sigma^3$ is given.

Tags: group-theory, permutations

This question is a repeat of [Finding the 'cube roots' of a permutation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317375/finding-the-cube-roots-of-a-permutation) , but since I can't comment there. Asking like this is the only option.

In my approach I assume $\sigma = (672918453)$

$\implies \sigma^2 = \begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9\\4&1&7&3&6&2&9&5&8 \end{pmatrix} $

$\implies \sigma^3 = \begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9\\5&8&2&6&7&9&1&3&4 \end{pmatrix} $

$\implies \sigma^3 =$ $(157)(283)(469)$

But Hints given at end of the book has elements (124586739) (142568793) (214856739).

I want to know what my mistake is here?

**Reference: Contemporary Abstract Algebra by Joseph Gallian**

**Thanks, now I can comment everywhere!**

Comment: Now you _can_ comment, since you have 50 reputation.

Comment: There are $18$ solutions of $\sigma^3=(157)(283)(469)$, not just three.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown to place first element of $\sigma$ there are 9 possibilities, but to place second element from other disjoint set there are still 6 possibilities, so how is it that there are 18 solutions to $\sigma^3=(157)(283)(469)$?

Comment: @VKSingh Going back to the solution in the linked question, relative to where you have placed 1, there are 6 places to place 2, and then there will only be 3 places to place 4.  6*3=18.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $9$-cycles you are after are of the form $\sigma=(a_1\>b_1\>c_1\>a_2\>b_2\>c_2\>a_3\>b_3\>c_3)$ whereby the three $a_i$s are placeholders for the three digits in one of the cycles of $\sigma^3$, and similarly for the $b_i$s and the $c_i$s. WLOG you can assume $a_1=1$; then necessarily $a_2=5$, $a_3=7$. For $b_1$ you have $6$ choices, namely one of $\{2,3,4,6,8,9\}$. After you have made a choice $b_2$ and $b_3$ are determined. For $c_1$ there are $3$ choices left, and then $c_2$ and $c_3$ are determined. It follows that there are $6\cdot3=18$ permutations $\sigma$ with $\sigma^3=(157)(283)(469)$.